# unordered_map insert on past-the-end iterator

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, unordered-map

Is it defined and valid behavior that insert through pass-the-end iterator returned by `find` when the key is not found:

```
auto it = m.find(key);
if (it == m.end()) {
    m.insert(it, make_pair(key, value));
}
```

because this will save an additional lookup compared using:

```
m[key] = value;
```

Comment: What's your reasoning behind this saving a lookup? `m[key]` will return a reference to either the existing element or the value-initialized element it just created.

Comment: The iterator passed to `insert` is only a hint.  Implementations are free to ignore it.  If the hint is used and is bad, a regular insert will be done.  Maybe you should look at `try_emplace`?

Comment: Looking at the implementations, both libc++ and the MSVCRT completely ignore the iterator hint to `insert`.

Comment: ok, can i use `it->first = key; it->second = value` then?

Comment: @fluter, No, you can't pretend a past-the-end iterator points to an actual object.

Comment: `m[key] = value;` performs one lookup.

Comment: @L.F. the find already performed a lookup, is there any way to use one lookup for the whole thing?

Comment: Why do you need `find`? Doesn’t `m[key]` do everything under the hood?

Comment: @L.F. because if old value is found, i need to do something with it

Comment: @fluter Then you should update your question to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

While it's safe to pass an end iterator as a hint to to `unordered_map::insert`, it doesn't actually accomplish anything.

Of the three major standard library implementations, only libstdc++ does anything with that hint, and even then it will only end up using it if it points to a valid entry.

If you want to avoid doing two lookups (one to determine if the element is present and another to insert it), you should just try to insert it.  `insert` returns both a `bool` denoting whether a new element was inserted and an iterator to either the newly-inserted element or the existing element that prevented insertion.  That means the most efficient way to insert an element if it doesn't exist and get an iterator to the element is to do something like this:

```
decltype(m)::iterator it;
bool inserted;
std::tie(it, inserted) = m.insert(std::make_pair(key, value));
if (inserted) {
    // ...
}
```

If your `mapped_type` is expensive to construct, you can avoid building it with `try_emplace` (only available with C++17 or later):

```
auto [it, inserted] = m.try_emplace(key, args, to, value, constructor);
if (inserted) {
    // ...
}
```

Pre C++17, you can just let `operator[]` default-construct the element and compare the container size to determine if a new element was added:

```
size_t size_before = m.size();
ValueType& element = m[key];
size_t size_after = m.size();
if (size_before != size_after) {
    element = ValueType{args, to, value, constructor};
    // ...
}
```

Obviously this has the drawback of default-constructing the element and only working with assignable types.